# How can I retrieve my product key without the disc or case?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to retrieve my product key on my MacBook Pro?  I purchased it from Amazon on August 19, 2011.

Comment: Your product key for what product? MacBook Pros don't have product keys.

Answer (score 2):

Your Macbook Pro doesn't have a product number; it has a *serial number.*

You can obtain your serial number by looking at the bottom of your Macbook Pro or by clicking  the "apple" at the top of the screen and selecting *About This Mac*

[image]

Once to select about this Mac, you will get a screen similar to the ones below that will give you your serial number.

### For Mavericks or earlier....

[image]

### For Yosemite and later....

[image]